# Getting Arduino 1.0.x to run on Guix: error: expected initializer before ‘_GLIBCXX_NORETURN’, error: ‘std::abort’ has not been declared, etc

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm looking to get arduino 1.0.x to work on my Mint/Guix hybrid box in order to hack around with 3D printer firmware. Unfortunately I can't get the stock `void setup () {} void loop () {}` to compile. I get the following compilation error:

```
  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
Arduino: 1.0.6 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Mega 2560 or Mega ADK"
In file included from /home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/stdlib.h:36,
                 from /home/blueberry/Software/arduino-old/arduino-1.0.6/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:23,
                 from sketch_jun23a.ino:3:
/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/cstdlib:57: error: expected initializer before ‘_GLIBCXX_NORETURN’
/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/cstdlib:59: error: expected initializer before ‘_GLIBCXX_NORETURN’
In file included from /home/blueberry/Software/arduino-old/arduino-1.0.6/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:23,
                 from sketch_jun23a.ino:3:
/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/stdlib.h:38: error: ‘std::abort’ has not been declared
/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/stdlib.h:40: error: ‘std::exit’ has not been declared
In file included from /home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/cmath:42,
                 from /home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/math.h:36,
                 from /home/blueberry/Software/arduino-old/arduino-1.0.6/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:25,
                 from sketch_jun23a.ino:3:
/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:69: error: expected `{' before ‘_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY’
/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:69: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
In file included from /home/blueberry/Software/arduino-old/arduino-1.0.6/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:235,
                 from sketch_jun23a.ino:3:
/home/blueberry/Software/arduino-old/arduino-1.0.6/hardware/arduino/variants/mega/pins_arduino.h:59: error: expected `}' at end of input
/home/blueberry/Software/arduino-old/arduino-1.0.6/hardware/arduino/variants/mega/pins_arduino.h:59: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

Guix clobbers the Arduino IDE include paths, even when my Nix environment is run. I can't get `snapd` to run on my box, setting up a custom Guix environment does not fix the problem, flathub doesn't have arduino 1.0.x available. Where can I go from here? Thanks.

Comment: `Guix clobbers the Arduino IDE include paths, even when my Nix environment is run. ` Isn't that a bug you should report to the Guix people? All the Arduino IDE should be doing is set up an environment where `PATH` correctly points to the used compiler, and then execute `avr-gcc` etc. (see e.g. https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/platform.txt#L20-L23) with some flags. It's quite miraculous to me how it's able to bend the include paths to end up finding `stdlib.h` in `/home/blueberry/.guix-profile/include/c++/stdlib.h`..